# Making tooltip behave like in scatter

Tags: jquery, highcharts, tooltip

Im working with 300 points at a time and the default behavior of the line graph is not great because of the close proximity of points. The scatter plot behaves different and does not have the issue that line does. How can I make the line tooltip behave like the scatter tooltip?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/akULB/) you can see how the tooltip works. It does not work by just hovering over a point but also hovering above the graph.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wRHcx/) you can see that event `sticky` tooltip is enabled the value does not change until you hover on another point.

Thanks

Comment: When you ask a question like this it's always good to provide some examples of what you are talking about.  I am using Highcharts with literally thousands of points per line chart as well as scatter plots and I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @RealityExtractor so you're telling me that on your charts the behavior of the tooltip is the same across all charts?

Comment: Well I suppose not.  So you want to be able to hover the mouse over the line of a plot and not have it trigger a tooltip unless you are close to an actual data point?

Comment: @RealityExtractor Yes.. I was wondering if there was some settings for that.

Comment: I don't think there's a setting for that.  You could experiment with snap in the tooltip, but I think it will display the closest value regardless of snap setting, even if you set it to 0.  Like so:  snap: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use scatter series, and just set `lineWidth: 2`, to get line between points and tooltip will remain the same, see: http://jsfiddle.net/wRHcx/2/

Comment: Thanks I thinks this is the closest thing to a solution.